# how to add slideshow in magento front-end

Tags: magento

Hi everybody May i know how to add slideshow in magento front end.

I installed magento 1.9

can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://www.magictoolbox.com

Step 1: Go to left sidebar -> hover on magic slideshow->click magento->download

step 2: unzip file->copy magicslideshow to magento folder

step 3: run localhost/website-name/magicslideshow/

step 4:Install(Before that go to magento admin panel->system->tools->compilation->If enable, do disable complilation)

step 5:After install enable the installation process.

step 6: After installation process finished, clear the cache

step 7: In admin panel go to magicslideshow ->edit-> enable slideshow and other settings.

step 8: Refresh the magento home page.

Answer (score 0):

You should download a slider module.
I prefer to use Dolphin Responsive Banner Slider and MKS Responsive Banner Slider.
You can download it from
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dolphin-responsive-slideshow.html

OR

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-banner-slider.html

Comment: that is because there are some configuration problem. You can download it from freegento. Copy the magento connect extension key in http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php , download it and copy those files in your project and configure it

Comment: you need to login then accept the terms and conditions and then click get extension key, select amnd copy it

Comment: jst log out and then log in to ur admin account

Comment: You need to configure it.

Comment: click on responsive banner slider tab from the top menu configure it

Comment: check them all and configure as per your requirement

Comment: check them add images and fill all the fields

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [this module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/complete-responsive-slider.html). It is very easy to use and there are many effect in this slider too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It saved my day.