# how to add slideshow in magento 1.7.0.2 front-end

Tags: magento

Hello everyone i want to add slideshow on page, i refereed below this url. I follwed all the given steps by Selva, but doesn't worked out for me.

i followed steps upto 2 but didn't understand 3-step. My side first it was taking default website name, then i changed it to "dap". For installing process, wrote url in address bar "localhost/dap/magicslideshow-trial" but it gives all files inside the folder. So using simple logic, took example7.html code for my use but it can't show slideshoe. It just shows images.

Am using magento ver 1.7.0.2. can anyone please help me to add slideshow on page. [[how to add slideshow in magento front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836565/how-to-add-slideshow-in-magento-front-end/30839030#30839030][1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-banner-slider.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-youama-jquery-nivo-slider.html

and follow there steps on extension page.